# How to sum rows of a table without hard references to column bounds

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table with an 'item' column that contains a string, and several columns for the amount spent on that item in different months of the year, like so:

| Item | Jan | Feb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 10 | 20 |
| Second | 35 | 3 |
| Third | 70 | 17 |

I then have a second table that should total each row, like so:

| Item | Total |
| --- | --- |
| First | 30 |
| Second | 38 |
| Third | 87 |

However, I cannot get this second table to total them properly. I realize that I could very easily achieve this by making each cell of Table2 `=SUM(B2:C2)` or something like that and extending it over the other rows. The issue is that 1) I want to use structured references and 2) I don't know how many months I will use this table for, so I want to add on a month as they pass by, and I don't want to adjust the formulas every month. I have several pairs of tables like this.

One idea I had to solve the first issue is this formula:
`=SUMIF(Table1[ITEM], [@ITEM], Table1[[Jan]:[Feb]])`
The idea being that it sums the row if the Item label is the same. However, when I add the March column I have to adjust the formula, which I don't want.

A similar idea to address the second problem is this formula:
`=SUMIF(Table1[ITEM], [@ITEM], Table1)`
The idea being that it sums the whole row, ITEM column included (but just takes a string as 0). But this doesn't work, the sum in each row comes to 0 for some reason. I think the string messes with it somehow.

Another idea is to add a 'Total' column to Table1 and keep everything in one table, but I can't sum the whole row without circular references. And again, specifying a column range means adjusting the formula every month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use INDEX to return the full row:

```
=SUM(INDEX(Table1,ROW($ZZ1),0))
```

[image]

Now as it fills down it will change which row it is returning.

We can change out `ROW($ZZ1)` for MATCH and not worry about order:

```
=SUM(INDEX(Table1,MATCH([@Item],Table1[Item],0),0))
```

[image]

As you can see neither refers to a column range (except the MATCH)  allowing the addition of columns in Table1 and it will adjust automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could can use the following to sum each entire row:

```
=SUM(Table1[@])
```

If you use that and subtract the Item column from it, it will do what you need:

```
=SUM(Table1[@]) - Table1[@Item]
```

In actuality, so long as the Item column is guaranteed to never have a numeric entry, not even a typo producing one, you need only the first piece. But to be safe... That goes for the use of `INDEX()` so it's a non-compete, but good for robustness.

`INDEX()` gets away from structured references by adding to them, in a way, rather than relying solely upon them when possible. Works well, but conceptually, if committed to the structural reference idea, while not as egregious as using a cell reference instead of the corresponding structured reference, it is still stepping out away from the idea.

Plus, it adds complexity that the structured reference does not as it is not a function. (Per se. In a way, it kind of is, eh?)

What makes it a winner though is the simplicity, which is actually dead rare with structured references.

Comment: Yeah but this assumes the tables are horizontally lined up. Which they're not. The tables are on top of eachother, because they will potentially grow to have very many columns .

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach: add a final column which contains nothing, called "do not use" for example, then you can include this last column in your range from Jan to [end]. When you insert March between Feb and this column your formula still just works.